# Use network bridge as default network in libvirt

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, bridge, libvirt

I created a network bridge `virtbr0` with my NIC `enp1s0f1`. The bridge gets an ip address from the router via dhcp. i would like to use the bridge as default network in libvirt to also get ip addresses for the respective VM via the router (dhcp server). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In the virtual machine configuration, use the following kind of interface entry:

```
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:1c:00:3a"/>
  <source bridge="virtbr0"/>
  <model type="e1000e"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

This provides an `e1000e` network adapter in the virtual machine, which is connected to the `virtbr0` bridge.